# How to create ForeignKey in Django that connects only part of foreign Queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm creating backend for Kiosks and each Kiosk model has Location model connected. But some locations have flag 'disabled'. I'm trying to remove this Locations from dropdown menu in Django Admin -> Kiosk so user couldn't choose it while creating/updating Kiosk instance.

I see two potential ways to solve it:

1. Edit Django admin page for Kiosk so in dropdown menu he can see only filtered results
2. Create proxy model with filtered results that would be connected to Kiosk

I would be happy to hear your suggestions, criticism

Let's suggest that models look like this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    '''Location of Kiosks'''

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Location"
        verbose_name_plural = "Locations"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField('Description')
    enabled = models.BooleanField('Location enabled', default=True)

class Kiosk(models.Model):
    '''Kiosk unit'''

    description = models.TextField('Description')
    uuid = models.CharField('Kiosk ID', unique=True, max_length=30)
    location = models.ForeignKey(to=Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) to limit the number of options:

```
class Kiosk(models.Model):
    '''Kiosk unit'''

    description = models.TextField('Description')
    uuid = models.CharField('Kiosk ID', unique=True, max_length=30)
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'enabled': True}
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) to your `ForeignKey` so that it's choices are filtered

```
location = models.ForeignKey(
    Location,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    limit_choices_to={'enabled': True},
)
```